# What are the chances of breeding a Legendary Dragon and how can I improve them?

Tags: dragon-city

I've read the [Wiki page about Legendary Dragon.](http://dragoncity.wikia.com/wiki/Legendary_Dragon). But the breeding details are unclear for me:

- Do I need to build a Legendary Habitat to have a chance to breed a Legendary Dragon?
- What is the chance of getting it when breeding pure dragons? 1 in 10? 1 in 50? 1 in 5?
- Do I have a higher chance of getting a Legendary Dragon when breeding 2 pure dragons or 2 pure hybrids?

Answer (score 1):

A legendary dragon has a 1% chance of being breed, no matter what you try. It's best to only do 2 pure dragons.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting a very high level mercury dragon. Pretty sure levels matter in breeding and mercury dragon has the most basic types for a hybrid + hybrid dragon, only water and metal, so shouldn't take that long to breed and hatch.

Pretty sure max level is 120.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! "pretty sure" is not a good way to prove your statement, you should link sources.